# my live usb has error Grub Rescue

Tags: 14.04, grub2, live-usb

my issue is NOT ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on HDD.

my issue is live usb getting error on boot "no such device: .....
grub Rescue > "

i know people say just format and remake whole live usb again. i don't want to do that again and again it consumes too much of my time, because on LIVE USB i have lot of apps configured to my needs and they work flawlessly.

i know "boot repair app" fixes this issue on HDD but how do i boot repair my live usb?

NOTE:
my linux mint mate 17.1 (ubuntu 14.04 lts) working great on my pc.
i am only having this issue on my linux mint mate 17.1 live USB

Answer (score 0):

You need to install/re-install grub on to the Live USB itself.

Assuming the Live USB is `/dev/sdc` for instance, you may get away with just

```
 grub-install /dev/sdc
```

if you are lucky. Otherwise you may need to go the more complex route as shown on

[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

except that you can do all that using your functioning HDD system instead of a Live CD.